# Zend Implementing SEO friendly or vanity URLs with router

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-router

I have a simple e-commerce web application with product URL's like:

```
http://www.example.com/product/view/product_id/15
```

where "Product" is the controller and "view" is the action in the Product Controller

How do I change this URL to show up as:

```
http://www.example.com/product/view/product_name/iphone-4S-16-gb
```

where `product_id` "15" is the primary key in the product table and `product_name` has the value "iphone 4s 16 gb" without the hyphens

What is the simplest way for me to make this change.
Would really appreciate your help.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
resources.router.routes.view-article.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
resources.router.routes.view-article.route = "articles/(?!archive)([a-zA-Z\-]+)/(\d+)(?:/(.*))?"
resources.router.routes.view-article.reverse = "articles/%s/%d/%s"
resources.router.routes.view-article.defaults.module = "articles"
resources.router.routes.view-article.defaults.controller = "view"
resources.router.routes.view-article.defaults.action = "view-article"
resources.router.routes.view-article.map.1 = topicSlug
resources.router.routes.view-article.defaults.topicSlug = topicSlug
resources.router.routes.view-article.map.2 = id
resources.router.routes.view-article.defaults.id = 0
resources.router.routes.view-article.map.3 = articleSlug
resources.router.routes.view-article.defaults.articleSlug = articleSlug
```

links like `http://example.com/articles/circus/616/4-marta-vse-za-ruletkami`

`http://example.com/products/category/product_id/product_name`

**EDIT 1**

this is a setup for default router plugin. shown as `articles` from my blog module, but easily updates for shop.

parts - `http://example.com/` is host :)  `articles/circus/` => module and controller mapeed.

`resources.router.routes.view-article.map.1 = topicSlug` is a category. for shop.

`616/4-marta-vse-za-ruletkami` ID and any slug. product description, for example, 'iphone-4S-16-gb
'

defaults are in config.

another example `/{maps2module}/{maps2topicSlug}/{maps2id}/{maps2articleSlug}`

Comment: Perhaps a little explanation?

Comment: Thank SMka for your input but I'm very new to this topic and I'm not able to grasp my head around it. Is there any simple tutorial I can read about it

Comment: there is nothing simple in ZF :)))) but read docs. there are tons of examples. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html